# How to get vim-snipmate's console.log to use double quotes instead of single

Tags: javascript, vim, snipmate

`cl <TAB>` outputs `console.log(': ', );`

How do I change the default behavior from using single quotes to double?
It would be best if I can set a setting in my *.vimrc* file.

If not then perhaps it is possible to patch `~/.vim/bundle/vim-snippets/snippets/javascript/javascript.snippets` myself:

```
235 snippet cl "console.log"
236   console.log(${0});
```

I could not see any single quotes that I could replace with double. Any idea how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 2):

The expected behaviour is:

```
cl               type 'cl'
<Tab>            press '<Tab>'
console.log(|);  replace the 'cl' stub with 'console.log()',
                 with the cursor between the parentheses.
```

You are simply not supposed to see *anything* between the parentheses until you start typing.

Either…

- You have a mapping or *something* of your own interfering with Snipmate:

  1. look up the output of `:verbose imap`, `:verbose smap`, and `:verbose vmap`,
  2. disable your mappings and autocommands to see if the problem persists.
- You have another plugin interfering with Snipmate:

  1. disable all your plugin to see if the faulty behaviour changes,
  2. if it does, try bisecting your plugins until you find the culprit… and act accordingly.
- You have stumbled upon a bug in Snipmate:

  1. set up a minimal reproducible case,
  2. use the plugin's issue tracker to report the bug and help getting it fixed.

Comment: I did an other grep and found this: `vim-es2015-snippets/UltiSnips/javascript.snippets:   92 console.log('${2:$1: }', ${1});`

Comment: patched it there. :-)